# Regex : validate length, must contain digits, must contain 3 hyphens

Tags: regex, phone-number

I'm looking for a regex for validating phone numbers.

Here is what I'd like my regex to validate:

- Must be 14 to 17 characters in length
- Must be all digits and contain 3 hyphens

Accepted formats:

```
5-555-555-5555
55-55-555-5555
55-555-555-5555
555-555-555-5555
5555-555-555-5555
```

My current code looks like this:

```
^.*(?=.{14,17})(?=.*\-{3,})(?=.*[\d\-]).*$
```

It is allowing more than 3 hyphens and the length is being allowed to exceed 17 characters.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an ugly brute force version that simply lists the 4 valid formats explicitly:

```
^(\d-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})|(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4})|(\d{2}-(\d{3}-){2}\d{4})|((\d{3}-){3}\d{4}$)|(^\d{4}-(\d{3}-){2}\d{4})$
```

Here is the [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/SDPzD1tcfX) link.

Comment: This achieves my original request and then goes further my enforcing formatting as well.  I have no problem with brute force in this application.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @mduschak:  With regular expressions, I sometimes prefer brute force over clever simply for maintenance purposes.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
/^(?=.{14,17}$)(\d+-){3}\d+$/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
/(?=^.{14,17}$)^\d+-\d+-\d+-\d+$/.test('2332-32332-233-22')
```

`(?=.{14,17})` first asserts using lookahead that the length of the string is in between 14 and 17 characters. Then it matches to see that there are three hyphens between the digits. `^ and $` makes sure that there is nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but i took the challenge and made an edited non-bruteforce version of Amber's answer.

```
/^(?=.{14,17}$)\d{1,4}(?:\-\d{3}){3}\d$/
```

This has the ability to enforce format (x{1,4}-xxx-xxx-xxxx) and is shorter than Mark Wilkins' answer.

Amber's answer is incomplete cause it doesn't enforce format (5-555-555-5555555 is validated when it clearly states that isn't a valid format), but it does enforce length with -1 char than Narendra Yadala's answer.

**EDIT (14/01/2014):**

This is a reduced answer:

```
/^\d{1,4}(?:\-\d{3}){3}\d$/
```

What i did was simple: i took away the lookahead.

It was useless in this case.

This one is -13 chars long that the Narendra Yadala's answer and -12 chars than my previous.